# Google maps marker is not getting displayed

Tags: google-maps, android, markers

I am trying to learn google map API. I see a map but I am unable to get a marker. Here is my code

**Activity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco"));
    }

}
```

**home_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 1):

Probably map is null after getMap(). it needs some time to get initialised. 
Try to wait somehow, or put addMarker into onResume().

Answer (score 1):

`getMap()` is deprecated. Use callback `setOnMapLoadedCallback` which is called when the map finishes loading.

```
googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {

//Add markers here
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 15));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same error here. 
Instead to use setContentView(), I've used intent.

I call the Navigator activity from main_activity, using a button.

Try this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Navigator.class);
 startActivity(intent);`